# Why the following code printing garbage value?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop, garbage

I am not able to understand why the following code printing garbage value

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main(){
 int arr[5],i=0;
 while(i<5)
    arr[i]=++i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
 }
```

Comment: BTW: you should indent your code properly. Readable code = code easier to debug

Comment: `arr[i]=++i;` you really want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
arr[i]=++i;
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
i = i + 1;
arr[i] = i;
```

Which means you will not initialize the first element (at index `0`) in the array. What's worse is that you will write at index `5` as well, and that's *out of bounds* and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value, which could be seen as random or garbage.

I recommend that you have a `for` loop like the one used for printing the values for your initialization as well:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = i + 1;
```

Comment: so when we assigning `i`'s value first it increments i and then consider the expression `a[ i ]`?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.  Your suggested translation might be a possibility, but it isn't the only one.  They're all bad, though, since the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara — not necessarily, though it's a possibility.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you mean by not necessarily?

Comment: The increment must be complete when execution passes the semicolon.  When it is done is mostly up to the compiler.  The value of `i` is both modified and read without an intervening sequence point; the behaviour is undefined.  If the machine melts because of it, that's fine too (unlikely, but permissible).  Simply don't do it.  You can't tell what the result should be because there is no defined (required) result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This program gives a correct output when we replace the statement `arr[i]=++i` as `arr[i++]=i;` why is that?

Comment: There is no ”correct output”!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210140/discussion-between-neminda-prabhashwara-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara General hint: don't use constructs where you have `x` and `x++` in the same statement.Not only the code is hard to understand, but in many cases you also get undefined behaviour. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The expression `arr[i] = ++i` is *undefined* as you are reading and writing from and to `i` at the same time.

`=` is not a *sequencing point* so you can't assume that `i` is increased prior to taking the index of `arr`.

**Even if** `i` was increased prior to taking the index of `arr` (as it is required to in some languages such as C++17, then the program behaviour would still be undefined due to an out of bounds array access).